# Understanding sentry nodestore_node table

Tags: python, mysql, django, sentry

I want to write my own cleanup script for sentry database. I understand how every other tables are linked except for `nodestore_node` table. It has three columns,

```
id, data, timestamp
```

Surely none is a foreign key, hence its id must be used as foreign key in some other table. I cannot figure out which one. I tried looking into `bind_nodes` method in `src/sentry/db/models/manager.py` to figure out how data is being fetched from nodestore_node for a particular event, but couldn't understand from there (I don't have much background in django/python). Is `data` attribute in `sentry_message` table is what I should look into ?

Can someone help me understand how `nodestore_node` table fit into the entire schema.

Comment: What is the problem you are trying to solve here?

Comment: Custom cleanup script. Given a sentry_message.message_id, how do you find data for that event from nodestore_node ?

Comment: Its stored in a pickled json format - again, I ask you - what it is that you are trying to do because it looks like you are going about it the "hard" way; you can easily write a custom plugin which will get signals from Sentry with the data in a format that you can use instead of doing this, whatever it is that you are actually trying to do.

Comment: We both trying to create a custom cleanup scripts, because the sentry out-of-the-box cleanup a) is opaque b) seems like it merey doesn't work at all. For instance my sentry database has the size off 203 gigs, though I run sentry cleanup each day.